# Extracting values from list having multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dataframe which contains column exactMatch

```
select A.lead_id,A.allocated_to_id,A.leadsourceid,
   case when leadsourceid in ('Own Referral','Field Activity') THEN 'OWN REFERRAL'
        WHEN leadsourceid in ('Branch walk-in') THEN 'Branch walkin'
        ELSE 'CENTRALIZED LEAD'
     END AS LEAD_CATEGORY,
     A.lead_type,
    b.emp_grade,b.emp_dept,b.emp_cod_name,b.emp_doj
   from
   ids_dmz.CRM_ALL_LEAD_DATA A
   left join ids_dmz.emp_mstr b
   on A.allocated_to_id=b.emp_id
  where b.emp_doj between '01-Apr-2020' and '31-Dec-2023'
  AND b.EMP_DEPT='BABP'
  AND b.EMP_COD_NAME IN ()
  and B.emp_grade in ('09S','10S','11S','12S')

Policy Bazaar
PSF NPS
Aristo
UPPER NORTH
MAHINDRA
POLICYX
DM CHANNEL
GIRNAR
PUNJAB ROYALS
RRB
BBK
STRIVE INSURANCE BROKERS
ESAF
Retirement & Protection
PNB ONLINE
CARE
```

I want to achieve output like

unique allocated_to_id,no of total leads ,count_of own refferal, count_of branch walkin, count of centralized lead. how can I achieve that.

Comment: You might want to use pretty print or something to get that data as multiline (readable) text

Comment: @MatBailie done please help

Comment: It's still all one line

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your database (here exported as json)

```json
{
  "exactMatch": [
    {
      "clientId": 54,
      "otherStuff": "..."
    },
    {
      "clientId": 87,
      "otherStuff": "..."
    }
  ],
  "otherStuff": "..."
}
```

Loading the json file using the data above

```py
import json

info = open('dataset.json')
response_df_conso = json.load(info)
```

Then selecting only this information works

```
clientIds = [entry['clientId'] for entry in response_df_conso['exactMatch']]
print(clientIds)
```

```
>>> [54, 87]
```

Maybe i didn't understand your data structure clearly?

Answer (score 0):

```
def map_values(row):
    mapped_values = []
    for value in row:
        for val in value:
            if val not in value_to_number:
                value_to_number[val] = current_number
                current_number += 1
            mapped_values.append(value_to_number[val])
    return mapped_values

df['id2'] = df['id2'].apply(lambda x: [int(v) for v in x])
df['id2'] = df['id2'].apply(map_values)

# Create a dictionary to reverse the mapping
number_to_value = {v: k for k, v in value_to_number.items()}

def reverse_mapping(row):
    return [number_to_value[v] for v in row]

df['id2'] = df['id2'].apply(reverse_mapping)

print(df)
```

Comment: Are you the same Abhishek who asked the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
input_df.apply(lambda x: [row for row in [x['PI_CLNTNUM']] + response_df_conso.loc[(response_df_conso['exact_client_id']==x['PI_CLNTNUM']),
                                                                                  'prob_client_id'].values] if x['is_present'] else[],axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    A.allocated_to_id AS unique_allocated_to_id,
    COUNT(A.lead_id) AS no_of_total_leads,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEAD_CATEGORY = 'OWN REFERRAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_of_own_referral,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEAD_CATEGORY = 'Branch walkin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_of_branch_walkin,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.LEAD_CATEGORY = 'CENTRALIZED LEAD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_of_centralized_lead
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.lead_id,
            A.allocated_to_id,
            A.leadsourceid,
            CASE
                WHEN leadsourceid IN ('Own Referral', 'Field Activity') THEN 'OWN REFERRAL'
                WHEN leadsourceid = 'Branch walk-in' THEN 'Branch walkin'
                ELSE 'CENTRALIZED LEAD'
            END AS LEAD_CATEGORY,
            A.lead_type
        FROM
            ids_dmz.CRM_ALL_LEAD_DATA A
            LEFT JOIN ids_dmz.emp_mstr B ON A.allocated_to_id = B.emp_id
        WHERE
            B.emp_doj BETWEEN '01-Apr-2020' AND '31-Dec-2023'
            AND B.EMP_DEPT = 'BABP'
            AND B.EMP_COD_NAME IN (
               
            )
            AND B.emp_grade IN ('09S', '10S', '11S', '12S')
    ) A
GROUP BY A.allocated_to_id
```